# How to build keras classification model using two text features as input

Tags: keras, text-classification

I am trying to build a text classification model which uses two input text features to finally predict `10` classes but I need to give significant impact for each input branch on the final output i.e. each branch should participate with 50% of the final decision

currently the setup am trying to achieve is as below

```
from keras import Input
from keras.models import Sequential, Model
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation
from keras.layers.merge import concatenate

# input
input_1 = Input(shape=(x1_train[0].shape))  # , dtype = 'int32')
input_2 = Input(shape=(x2_train[0].shape))  # , dtype = 'int32')

desc = Sequential()
desc.add(Dense(5, activation='relu', input_shape=x1_train[0].shape))
desc.add(Dropout(0.2))
desc.add(Dense(10, activation='sigmoid'))

tax = Sequential()
tax.add(Dense(5, activation='relu', input_shape=x2_train[0].shape))
tax.add(Dropout(0.2))
tax.add(Dense(10, activation='sigmoid'))

# conact
concat = concatenate([desc, tax])
final_model = Sequential()
final_model.add(concat)
final_model.add(Dropout(0.5))
final_model.add(Dense(10, activation='softmax'))

# compile
model = Model(inputs=[input_1, input_2], outputs=final_model)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['acc'])
print(model.summary())
```

my question is, would this be the best practice or I should look into something else ?

Comment: So why do you have two dense layers for the two inputs? Can you not use just a single dense layer and concatenate the text features at input level? That will get rid of one additional matrix multiplication.

Comment: I want to treat each of the text feature as weighted decisioning points, i.e.  if feature_txt_1 result is `100%` class `A` and feature_txt_2 is `100%` class `A` I would get final result `A`
but if feature_txt_2 is `100%` class `B`, I would get final reuslt as `50% A and 50% B`, hope this explains my point

Comment: Yup it did. So is there anything you're particularly worried about in this implementation? Because I don't see anything that immediately stands out.

Comment: Am concerned of the type of layers, should I use `Dense` ? or `Embedded` or change the layers in general? should I add any more layers  ?

Comment: So about using `Embedding` layers - Usually in NLP problems yes that helps. But again it comes to how much data you have and how much domain-specific your problem is. The more domain-specific your problem, the higher the chance that you'll need to retrain the embeddings. And adding more layers, again depends on the type of the problem you're trying to solve and how much data you got. For example adding more layers when you have too little data leads to overfitting.

Comment: @thushv89 could check the updated network and check if the archetictures seems legit ?

Comment: so are you able to run you code? Because this is not typically how you would use the Sequential API (For example, afaik you can't create a `Model` where the inputs/outputs are models - I could be wrong, but at least it's not common). And do you have separate data to train all these models separately? Or is the final model dependent on the outputs of the previous models?

Comment: I will reconsider the `Sequential` and `Model`APIs, but what do mean if I "have data to train all these models", I thought this would be a single model with 2 inputs (branches) and am trying to evaluate each branch seperatley then evaluate combined result or that would be wrong ?

Comment: so let me get this straight. You have two models for two inputs. And then you have a larger model that is built on top of the concatenated outputs from the previous two models. I'm not sure how you can evaluate branches separately. Because your final model depends on outputs from both networks and whatever it learns it needs both those inputs.

Comment: it seems  am doing something wrong then, I have two text inputs which I need to feed into a single model but I want the features extraced from **each** input to have a significant impact on final the result

Comment: Okay now it makes more sense. So you want the features extracted (i.e. last output layer) of each model to impact the final output. But do you also want to use the inputs along with the feature outputs or just feature outputs? And I assume you have a single loss function.

Comment: only the feature outputs, let's imagine that it's like we had two separate models predicition same classes but using different feature inputs ... say one model uses image as input and the other uses text as input and we want to merge both in one model, also I have edited the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the simplest form I can come up for this question is the following.

```
from tensorflow.keras import Input
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation, Concatenate

n_desc_features = 10
n_tax_features = 20

# Input layers
input_1 = Input(shape=(n_desc_features,))  # , dtype = 'int32')
input_2 = Input(shape=(n_tax_features,))  # , dtype = 'int32')

# Getting model 1 output
desc_out = Dense(5, activation='relu')(input_1)
desc_out = Dropout(0.2)(desc_out)
desc_out = Dense(10, activation='sigmoid')(desc_out)
# Getting model 2 output
tax_out = Dense(5, activation='relu')(input_2)
tax_out = Dropout(0.2)(tax_out)
tax_out = Dense(10, activation='sigmoid')(tax_out)

# Concatenating and creating the final output
concat = Concatenate(axis=-1)([desc_out, tax_out])
final_out = Dropout(0.5)(concat)
final_out = Dense(10, activation='softmax')(final_out)

# Create the model and compile
model = Model(inputs=[input_1, input_2], outputs=final_out)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['acc'])
print(model.summary())
```

Hope it is pretty straight-forward what is happening here. You have two sub-models created. One produces `desc_out` and the other produces `tax_out`.

Then using those two outputs you create the final model output `final_out`. And you use that along with the input layers to create a `Model` object.

I think using `Sequential` is unnecessary here and you don't need to explicitly have models for the two sub-models as you're not doing optimization particular to sub-models, rather you optimizer the full thing at once.

Comment: Does this approach scale to more than one feature? For example for a tokenised sentence, I'd have ~10 features per token. E.g. the token itself, the token position, whether the token starts with a capital letter etc.